# Computing the limit of a function given the limit of its derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f\in C^\infty$ and $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, is it true that
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f'(x)=0\Rightarrow\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=a$$
for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$? I believe this is true due to the mean value theorem but I can't seem to properly show it, any help on where to start?

Comment: So, taking $g=f'$ you wonder: If $g(x) \to 0$, then must $\int_0^\infty g(x)\;dx$ converge? ... Perhaps you know a counterexample to this.

Comment: Great way to see it. Thank you for your comment

Comment: In general I think the function $f(x)=ln(x)$ is a good example to see why you might have trouble proving this conjecture. Due to the conditions $f$ must satisfy though it is hard to find a good counter-example.

Comment: Notice also that the implication is not true, even if you allow $a$ to be infinite. For example, such a thing like $\sin(\sqrt{x})$ has a derivative which tends to $0$, but has no limit in $+\infty$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe That's better than my answer.

Comment: You should notice that we have $f(x) /x\to 0$ via L'Hospital's Rule. But this does not give us any information about limit of $f(x) $.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe but the derivative of $\sin(\sqrt{x})$ is not always positive, right?

Comment: @RayBern Oh you are right, I forgot this asumption !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log x$ is unbounded, in $C^\infty$, but its derivative tends to zero.

It is not defined over the whole of  $\mathbb R$, but we can easily fix by replacing $x$ by the asymptotic equivalent $\log(e^x+1)$, which is monotonous.

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \log(\log(e^x+1))$

[image]

Comment: @DavidK: quite right. See the fix.

Answer (score 1):

How about $f(x) = \sinh^{-1} (x)$?
Then $f'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} > 0$
and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f'(x)=0.$

Comment: Nice example didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

Another example: $f(x) = \ln(2+x^2)\arctan x.$